# Converting from Linq byte[] Concat to older .net Array with copy and Length considerations

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I have business need that requires keeping an application at .net 2.0   :(

Thus after reverting from .net 4.5.1 to .net 2.0  and then  REMOVING

```
 using System.Linq;
```

I end up with an error with this line of code (and a few other lines)
How can I fix this to work in .net 2.0 ?

```
 byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(passwordBytes.Concat(salt).ToArray());
```

`'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and no extension method 'Concat' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Complete Method for reference:

```
public static byte[] CreatePasswordHash(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations = 60000)
    {
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

            // step 2
            byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(passwordBytes.Concat(salt).ToArray());

            // step 3
            byte[] result = sha256.ComputeHash(salt.Concat(hash).ToArray());

            // step 4
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                result =
                    sha256.ComputeHash(salt.Concat(result).ToArray());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to go to reference source and copy their code into the project.. easy does it

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9c0a66e386e37265

Comment: @EyalPerry .NET 2.0 does not have extension methods so it's not as simple as copying source code.

Comment: Extension methods are merely syntactic sugar.. you can still use the static methods of a class..@DStanley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you only want to concatenate two arrays into a single array. You can use `Array.Copy` to create the following method:

```
public static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(T[] array1, T[] array2)
{
    T[] newArray = new T[array1.Length + array2.Length];

    Array.Copy(array1, 0, newArray, 0, array1.Length);

    Array.Copy(array2, 0, newArray, array1.Length, array2.Length);

    return newArray;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public static byte[] CreatePasswordHash(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations = 60000)
{
    using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        // step 2
        byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(ConcatArrays(passwordBytes, salt));

        // step 3
        byte[] result = sha256.ComputeHash(ConcatArrays(salt, hash));

        // step 4
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            result = sha256.ComputeHash(ConcatArrays(salt, result));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks so much.